# React / Redux: Patch fetch updates in my database, but struggling to pass proper data to my reducer to update state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, semantic-ui

### Background

I have an array of television program objects. The objects contain the name, network, and image for the program. On each item in the array, I have a heart button. The heart allows the user to add the program to a watchlist. Each program is created with a watchlist attribute which is set to false. Clicking the button will toggle the watchlist attribute to true or false.

### Troubleshooting Done So Far

I know my update case statement involves returning the following items:
1) Make a copy of my current state;
2) Make a copy of my current programs array;
3) Pass in my updated program.

I'm using `debugger` to find out what data is being passed from my dispatch to my reducer. Then, I have used another `debugger` inside my reducer to find out how I should manipulate that data to return my updated state and re render the DOM.

I tried following along with [this blog](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/crud-using-react-41d047224e26/) but I didn't quite understand how to apply what was said to my own project.

### Code Samples

Here is the callback method in my **Program component**. It is passing the programId and watchlistValue. I have confirmed that these are the correct values by using console.log to check.

```
handleWatchlist = (programId, watchlistValue) => {

    this.props.toggleWatchlist(programId, watchlistValue)

  }
```

**If you would rather see the entire file you can find it [here](https://github.com/koberlander/tv-list-frontend/blob/master/src/components/programs/Program.js)**

Here is my **toggleWatchlist action**. My fetch is successfully updating my database, but I fear I am dispatching incorrectly in my last .then statement.

```
export function toggleWatchlist(programId, watchlistValue){
  console.log('programId: ', programId)
  console.log('watchlistValue: ', watchlistValue)

  // debugger
  // used debugger to figure out what to send as the TOGGLE_WATCHLIST payload

  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({type: 'START_TOGGLE_WATCHLIST_REQUEST'})

    fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/programs/${programId}`, {
      method: 'PATCH',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        watchlist: !watchlistValue
      })
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => dispatch({type: 'TOGGLE_WATCHLIST', id: programId}))

  }
}
```

Here is my **programReducer case statement**. I know that `action.watchlist` contains my new watchlist value.

```
  case 'TOGGLE_WATCHLIST':

    console.log('inside TOGGLE_WATCHLIST case');
    console.log("use debugger to figure out what your 'payload' is here (or whatever you are passing in)");

    // debugger
    // used debugger to figure out how to pass in updated item to programs array.

    const toggledProgram = state.programs.map(program => program.id === action.programId)

     // action.watchlist contains new watch value. it is the one thing needing change. However, do I just update the entire program? It will include watchlist value.
     return {...state, programs: [...state.programs, toggledProgram]}
```

**If you need to see the entire file, you can find it [here](https://github.com/koberlander/tv-list-frontend/blob/master/src/reducers/programReducer.js).**

In addition to those code issues, I have been plagued throughout the course of this project by console errors that indicate my cards need a key prop. I have tried passing in the program.id, the program.title, and simply passing index into my .map error function. All to the same result. Am I placing the key on the proper part of my card component? **[Full code file here](https://github.com/koberlander/tv-list-frontend/blob/master/src/components/programs/Programs.js)**

```
    <Grid columns='six' divided='vertically'>
          <Grid.Row >
              {props.programs.map((program) => <Program key={program.name} 
                 program={program} />)}
          </Grid.Row>
    </Grid>
```

### Recap of Questions

- Am I dispatching my action properly after my fetch call? I know that if I am sending incorrect info to my reducer than I will not be able to update my state correctly.
- Have I placed my key value on the correct part of my card component?

#### Thank you for your time and attention!